# Opening a plot in tkinter only (no matplotlib popup)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I am opening a matplotlib pyplot in a tkinter window with the below code. My issue is that the plot is still popping up in the matplotlib window as well, and I don't know how to stop that. I've tried commenting out each of the plt.plot's but that didn't help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import Tkinter as Tkinter

def tester():

    class window(Tkinter.Tk):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.initialize()

        def initialize(self):
            self.grid()
            self.grid_rowconfigure(0,minsize=50)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(1,minsize=5)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(2,minsize=500)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(3,minsize=5)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(4,minsize=20)

            self.grid_columnconfigure(0,minsize=5)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(1,minsize=800)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(2,minsize=5)

            framer = Tkinter.Frame(self, borderwidth=2, relief='groove',bg='white')
            framer.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=3,rowspan=3, sticky='NSEW')
            Button1 = Tkinter.Button(bg='red',text="Click Me",command=self.onbutton1)
            Button1.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='NSEW')


        def onbutton1(self):
            array = np.array([[1,2,3,2,1],[2,3,4,3,2],[3,4,5,4,3],[4,5,6,5,4],[3,4,5,4,3]])
            maximum = np.max(array)
            index_max = np.where(array == maximum)
            max_a, max_b = index_max  

            plotter=plt.figure('plot')            
            plt.contour(array, linewidths = 1, colors = 'k')
            plt.contourf(array, cmap = plt.cm.jet)
            plt.ylabel('y', fontdict = {'fontsize':16})
            plt.xlabel('x', fontdict = {'fontsize':16})
            plt.colorbar()
            plt.title('Title', fontdict = {'fontsize':20})    
            plt.plot(max_b, max_a, 'wo')
            F_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plotter, self)
            F_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1,row=2)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = window(None)
        app.title('Window')
        app.mainloop()

tester()
```

Can anyone be my hero?

Comment: You can number figures --  i.e., plt.figure(1) -- and then work on them.  They shouldn't appear until you use plt.show(1).  That might suppress the matplotlib window, if you don't ever "show" it.

Comment: @JKelly I haven't used plt.show() at all in the above code. Am I 'showing' it in a different way?

Comment: Well, I was suggesting that numbering them "holds" them until their numbers are called, but BrenBarn's advice below is probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manage all the windows yourself, you should not use pyplot at all.  When you do `plt.figure`, for instance, it is creating a matplotlib-managed figure window.

Don't even import pyplot.  Exactly how to adapt your code will vary depending on what matplotlib features you use, but, for instance, to create the figure you'll want to do:

```
from matplotlib import figure
plotter = figure.Figure()
```

You'll access most of the plot types (such as `contour`) by accessing an Axes object of that Figure and using its methods (e.g., if you have an axes `ax` you can cal `ax.contour`).

See [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) for a simple demo of how to embed matplotlib in a Tkinter app.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am a rank beginner at this... what is the syntax to make an axes ax?

Comment: @JohnCrow: I think you can do `ax = plotter.gca()` to get an Axes for the figure.